# Setting boundaries for datetime x axis on Plotly (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plotly, scatter-plot

I have to plot some chronologically-ordered values (one value per month, in my case) on a Plotly (Python) graph. Also, I have to add a "end of period label" (i.e. a marker with text indicating the last value of the series) **that has to be positioned at 'middle right'**.

A working example would be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

date_range = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2013', end='9/1/2022', freq='M').tolist()).date
values = np.random.randint(100, size=len(date_range)).tolist()
fig = go.Figure(
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    showlegend=False,
    x=date_range,
    y=values,
    mode='lines',
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        color="red",
        )
    )
)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    showlegend=False,
    x=[date_range[-1]],
    y=[values[-1]],
    text=[values[-1]],
    textposition='middle right',
    texttemplate="%{text:.3f}",
    mode='markers+text',
    line=dict(
        width=2,
        color="red",
        )
    )
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickformat="%m\n<b>%Y", dtick="M3",
        )
)
```

which produces the following plot:[image: Plot for StackOverflow]

I am facing the following problem: the end of period label "extends" beyond the last value of the date range and makes the x axis go into the green area, which are all undesired months (for example, those that extend beyond the last value of the date range and into 2023).

I tried several things to "erase" or delete that undesired part of the x axis, but nothing worked properly: either the end of period label was cut in half or the whole x axis disappeared.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion.

Comment: The right side of the time series indicates the future, although a note is always required on the right side. If you want to place them on the left side, you can do the following. `fig.add_vline(x=pd.to_datetime(date_range[-1]).timestamp() * 1000,
              line_width=3,
              line_dash="dash",
              line_color="green",
              annotation_text=values[-1],
              annotation_position='top left'
             )`

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners for your response. I may have not been enough explicit in my needs (my bad), or I may not be understanding you correctly. Let me reexpress myself: I want to delete all those future values from the x axis, as they are only appearing because I inserted that end of period label, but do not contain relevant information (values). I do not want to plot the green rectangle on the picture, it was only there to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Adding a text mode for scatter plots automatically adds time series data for the length of the text, so you would use annotations or commented vertical line annotations. See here for more information on [annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/).

Comment: Thank you @r-beginners for your response. I now understand what you were trying to explain me. You were totally right, my bad. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as per @r0beginners comments
- given text is outside graph area use an annotation for the text
- make marker scatter just `mode=markers`
- explicitly state xaxis range `range=date_range[[0,-1]]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

date_range = pd.to_datetime(
    pd.date_range(start="1/1/2013", end="9/1/2022", freq="M").tolist()
).date
values = np.random.randint(100, size=len(date_range)).tolist()
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        showlegend=False,
        x=date_range,
        y=values,
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(
            width=2,
            color="red",
        ),
    )
)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    showlegend=False,
    x=[date_range[-1]],
    y=[values[-1]],
    mode='markers',
    marker_size=15
    )
)

fig.add_annotation(
    x = date_range[-1],
    y = values[-1],
    text = values[-1],
    xshift=10,
    yshift=0,
    showarrow=False
)


fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickformat="%m\n<b>%Y",
        dtick="M3",
        range=date_range[[0,-1]]
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rob Raymond for your response. It worked sensationally well. It was exactly what I was looking for. Credits to r-beginners for his response too.